# swiftui swipe action label disable dynamic type

Tags: ios, swiftui, custom-view, dynamictype, swiftui-swipeactions

How can I disable dynamic type to make the custom swipe action label look smaller when iOS font size is set to very large in Accessibility Setting?

My current solution is using the view modifier `.dynamicTypeSize(.xsmall)`, but it doesn’t seem to work.

[image: Screenshot of the current effect]

Comment: Looks to me like it worked. "Pin to top" is much smaller than the other text.

Comment: But if you swipe the first row of the list, where the text "11111" is only in one line, you can see the label only shows the pin icon without the text "Pin to top"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post your code as text then.

Comment: Also, this isn't really about dynamic type. There wouldn't have been enough space to show the label even if you use the default dynamic type size.